# Force detection of all words, even acronyms

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, system.speech.recognition

I need to recognize phrases like "CN Detector Yale".  I only want a successful recognition when ALL elements of the phrase are spoken, including the acronym.  However, I am finding that I am getting successful recognitions in cases where only "Detector Yale" is spoken.

Here is what I've been using:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer;
GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
gb.Append("CN Detector Yale");
recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(gb));
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

How can I force it to require all parts of the phrase for a successful match?

Comment: You need phonics for this... "See Enn Detector Yale" or something like that. Sorry, it has been a while since my AI class in grad school, but that's how we tackled it.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll  I tried "See Enn Detector Yale", as you suggested, but I am still getting recognitions when speaking just "Detector Yale".